# Mapping postgresql text[] in java

Tags: java, postgresql, mapping

have a nice day!

My question is:

I have a table in postgresql that have a field of type text[].

```
CREATE TABLE pregunta_contenido
(
    id_pregunta integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_pregunta_contenido'::regclass),
    contenido integer NOT NULL,
    num_pregunta integer,
    descripcion_pregunta text,
    respuesta text[],
    correcta text,
    CONSTRAINT pk_pregunta PRIMARY KEY (id_pregunta),
    CONSTRAINT fk_pregunta_contenido FOREIGN KEY (contenido)
    REFERENCES contenido (id_contenido) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

And i have a mapping of this table in a Java Application:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pregunta_contenido") 
public class PreguntaContenido {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_GEN")
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_GEN",sequenceName="seq_pregunta_contenido",allocationSize=1)
@Column(name="id_pregunta")
public Integer idPregunta;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="contenido", nullable=false)
public Contenido contenido;

@Column(name="num_pregunta")
public Integer numPregunta;

@Column(name="descripcion_pregunta")
public String descripcionPregunta;

@Column(name="respuesta")
public String respuesta;

@Column(name="correcta")
public String correcta;

}
```

When i am getting info, mapping is going well, but when i am setting it has an error because of type text[] and type string are not compatible.

How can i do to map in column respuesta a type who matches with type text[]?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a `String[]` or `List<String>`?

Comment: It drops a persistence error.

Comment: The annoying thing is that arrays aren't exactly standard, and I've been bitten by this before.  I'll rifle through some old projects to see if I have anything that could help you, but I do believe it involves creating your own custom type.

Comment: Thanks, Makoto. I'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

try bellow code after `@Entity` annotation :-

```
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "string-array",typeClass = StringArrayType.class)})
```

and use bellow code into entity :-

```
@Type( type = "respuesta" )
@Column(name = "respuesta", columnDefinition = "text[]")
private String[] respuesta;
```